# App was not installed error in Android sdk 19

Tags: android

I am using a kitkat device to debug my app,when i run the app i am getting this error.

```
PackageManager: mismatched uid for com.ex.app_name, try to erase old data
PackageManager: Package com.compny.app_name has mismatched uid: 10258 on disk, 10259 in settings
E/PackageManager: Unable to copy native libraries
                                           java.io.IOException: Cannot create /mismatched_uid/settings_10259/fs_10258
                                               at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.copyNativeLibrariesForInternalApp(PackageManagerService.java:5328)
                                               at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:4810)
                                               at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installNewPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:9348)
                                               at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:9794)
                                               at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$2300(PackageManagerService.java:182)
                                               at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$5.run(PackageManagerService.java:7512)
                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I have searched for this ,but i could not find a solution .Can anyone help?

Comment: Uninstall application for all user from your device. Error says application with same package name already exist in your device.

Comment: Hai Thank you but There is only one user account in my device..

Comment: & did you uninstall for that user?

Comment: Yes.I did. and tried again to install the app,but this erreor.And also the same app can install in lolipop,marshmallow and noughat devices .

Comment: @Gibs I think there is already an application with same package name installed "com.ex.app_name/com.compny.app_name" try to change the name in the manifest to something else.

Comment: @Gibs each app on your device is a separate user at the OS (linux) level.  When it says user, think app.  (The reason it does this is so it can use Linux filesystem permissions to block outside reads/writes to app private filesystems).